# How can I extract files from an Oracle BLOB field?

Tags: oracle, file, blob

I have a database which has a number of files stored in a BLOB field.

How can I extract & save the original files?  There are many different file types - doc, pdf, xls, etc.  The table has the extension in one col, and the original file name in another.  There may be multiple files with the same file name, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [UTL_FILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) package to do this in version 9i onwards

something like this:

```
DECLARE
  l_file      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  l_buffer    RAW(32767);
  l_amount    BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  l_pos       NUMBER := 1;
  l_blob      BLOB;
  l_blob_len  NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT blobcol
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   table
  WHERE  rownum = 1;

  l_blob_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_blob);

  -- Open the destination file.
  l_file := UTL_FILE.fopen(<location>,<filename>,'wb', 32767);

  WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
    l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
  END LOOP;

  -- Close the file.
  UTL_FILE.fclose(l_file);

END;
/
```

Comment: Since these are files you may want to use `wb` (write byte mode) instead of `w` (write text).

Comment: I believe if I take out where rownum = 1 this would write all the BLOBs from field. In that case, how do I make the filename dynamic i.e. make it use some other database field as filename? Moreover, can this write PDFs containing non-text stuff such as images?

Comment: The comparison operator in the `WHILE` condition should be `<=`, otherwise you run the risk of silently dropping the last byte or char from your LOB.