# ORACLE BLOB to FILE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob, blobs

I am writing some pl/sql to generate pdf reports that are stored as blobs in an oracle table. I need to loop through this table which has a column for filename and blob and write the blob to the OS as a file with the corresponding filename in the table. I pretty much have completed this code but am running into a snag:

```
ORA-06550: line 13, column 59:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SIMS_PROD"."PUBLISH_RPT_NEW"."RPT_FILE_NAME": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 13, column 12:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
Action:
```

I did read the post on the site: [How can I extract files from an Oracle BLOB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332032/how-can-i-extract-files-from-an-oracle-blob-field) - however - this is only for one file - my table contains hundreds of rows each that has a blob and associated filename - its the looping through this table thats giving me grief.

I need to prefix the schema name, table and column explicitly since I am logged in as a DBA user and not as the owner of the schema itself. Here is my code - what am I missing here or doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help from the community - its much appreciated.

```
DECLARE 
t_blob BLOB; 
t_len NUMBER; 
t_file_name VARCHAR2(100); 
t_output utl_file.file_type; 
t_totalsize NUMBER; 
t_position NUMBER := 1; 
t_chucklen NUMBER := 4096; 
t_chuck RAW(4096); 
t_remain NUMBER; 

BEGIN
  FOR X IN (SELECT SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_FILE_NAME,     SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_CONTENTS FROM SIMS_PROD.PUBLISH_RPT)

  LOOP
    -- Get length of blob 
    SELECT dbms_lob.Getlength (SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_CONTENTS),     SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_FILE_NAME INTO t_totalsize, t_file_name FROM     SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new;
    t_remain := t_totalsize; 

    -- The directory TEMPDIR should exist before executing 
    t_output := utl_file.Fopen ('PDF_REP', t_file_name, 'wb', 32760); 

    -- Get BLOB 
    SELECT SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_CONTENTS INTO t_blob FROM       SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new;

    -- Retrieving BLOB  
    WHILE t_position < t_totalsize 
      LOOP 
        dbms_lob.READ (t_blob, t_chucklen, t_position, t_chuck); 
        utl_file.Put_raw (t_output, t_chuck); 
        utl_file.Fflush (t_output); 
        t_position := t_position + t_chucklen; 
        t_remain := t_remain - t_chucklen; 

        IF t_remain < 4096 THEN t_chucklen := t_remain; 
        END IF; 
      END LOOP; 

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: `alter session set current_schema = sims_prod;` would eliminate the stated necessity of including schema in the anonymous block.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider writing a procedure separetly to save a BLOB as a file (any BLOB from any table) and then just loop through your table passing a BLOB, directory and file name. This way it could be used independently.
Here is the function (it is a function for some other reasons - you can change it to procedure) that does it like described:

```sql
Function BLOB2FILE (mBLOB BLOB, mDir VARCHAR2, mFile VARCHAR2) RETURN VarChar2
IS
BEGIN
  Declare
    utlFile       UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    utlBuffer     RAW(32767);
    utlAmount     BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
    utlPos        INTEGER := 1;
    utlBlobLen    INTEGER;
    mRet          VarChar2(100);
  Begin
    utlBlobLen := DBMS_LOB.GetLength(mBLOB);
    utlFile := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(mDir, mFile,'wb', 32767);
--
    WHILE utlPos <= utlBlobLen LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.READ(mBLOB, utlAmount, utlPos, utlBuffer);
      UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(utlFile, utlBuffer, TRUE);
      utlPos := utlPos + utlAmount;
    END LOOP;
--
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(utlFile);
    mRet := 'OK - file created' || mFile;
    RETURN mRet;
  Exception
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(utlFile) THEN
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(utlFile);
      END IF;
      mRet := 'ERR - CLOB_ETL.BLOB2FILE error message  ' || Chr(10) || SQLERRM;
      RETURN mRet;
  End;
END BLOB2FILE;
```

If you can select your BLOBS from any table just loop and pass it to the function/procedure with the directory and file name...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line 13 with this:

```
FOR X IN (SELECT RPT_FILE_NAME, RPT_CONTENTS FROM SIMS_PROD.PUBLISH_RPT)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a too late answer but at least you will know where have you done mistake. The problem is if you use:

`FOR X IN (SELECT a, b from table) LOOP`

You have to use `X.a` in next statements of this loop to properly refer to values of selected rows.

So in your code you had to change `SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_CONTENTS` to `X.SIMS_PROD.publish_rpt_new.RPT_CONTENTS`.

I haven't read the rest of your code, so maybe there could be some more mistakes too.

Answer (score 0):

have done a similar thing recently, 
ping me for exact additional details

but the gist is this

1. create/frame excel or pdf as blob and store in to a blob column
2. use a base 64 converter function to store the same data into clob ( as text )
3. use sqlplus from windows/linux to spool the text from the clob column
4. convert the clob to blob with desired filename using os tools (probably ssl/certificate has utility to convert b64 t0 binary back )