# Blob file download from databse to local folder which is having size greater >32767 using UTL oracle package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to download/export Blob data from database to local machine with the help of UTL package, but UTL package has a limit of 32767 bytes. is there are any alternative ways to download files .

Many thanks in advance

```
declare
    bblobb blob;
    v_buff raw(32767);
    v_buff_size binary_integer;
    v_amount binary_integer;
    v_offset number(38):=1;
    v_chunksize    INTEGER;
    v_out_file utl_file.file_type;
begin
    select blob_col  into bblobb from test_blob
    where id=12;
    v_chunksize := DBMS_LOB.GETCHUNKSIZE(bblobb);

    IF (v_chunksize < 32767) THEN
        v_buff_size := v_chunksize;
    ELSE
        v_buff_size := V_CHUNKSIZE;
    END IF;
    v_amount := v_buff_size;
    v_out_file:=utl_file.fopen('IMAGE','2.PDF','wb');
    dbms_lob.read(lob_loc=>bblobb, amount =>v_amount, offset =>v_offset, buffer =>v_buff);
    utl_file.put_raw(file =>v_out_file, buffer =>v_buff, autoflush =>true);
    utl_file.fflush(file=>v_out_file);
    utl_file.fclose(v_out_file);
end;
```

I need to download the file which is above the size 32767

Comment: Does "UTL package" mean "utl_file package"?  In which case you're quoting the maximum line size or the maximum chunk that can be written per call to `put_raw` not a limit on the size of the file that can be produced.  When you talk about the "local machine" is that the client machine?  Any code running in the database will be unable to write a file on the client system barring exceptionally unusual configurations (i.e. if the server mapped a drive from the client machine).

Comment: As Justin hints, you need to write the file out (to the server directory) in chunks of up to 32k - [as shown in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6332633/266304).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract files from an Oracle BLOB field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332032/how-can-i-extract-files-from-an-oracle-blob-field)