# Use Oracle SQL Developer to export BLOB's from table to a directory

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been tasked with writing a script to export BLOB's from an Oracle 11g database table, there are around 14,000. I've installed the most recent version of SQL Developer and can connect to the database.

My background is in MSSQL so this has been quite the learning curve! And after lots of googling, sweat, tears and cups of tea I've managed to cobble together a couple of scripts to do the job by using a cursor to iterate through the images table and a script to export the BLOB's from that table to a directory.

Basis of script 1 - Exporting BLOB's - [How can I extract files from an Oracle BLOB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332032/how-can-i-extract-files-from-an-oracle-blob-field) 
Basis of script 2 - Using Cursors - [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.htmlhttp://)

However I think it might be slow, my calculations show it will take around 11 hours to export the 14,000 images.

The script loops through the table and then there is a secondary loop which goes through the BLOB's themselves, so I'm guessing this can be improved upon?

I was running into an issue where utl_file process was locking files that were being exported however inserting "utl_file.fclose" after the BLOB export loop seemed to cure that for all but the last file being exported.

Bear in mind I'm a complete newby when it comes to Oracle!

The table I'm exporting from is caled "Images"
The BLOB Field is called "Image"
I am also exporting the columns "ID","ImageDate" and "ImageID" and appending ".jpg" as part of the filename.

I've tried to write some comments in case anyone comes across this at a later date. Here's the script, any help or comments will be greatly appreciated!

```
SET serveroutput on                     --Set to output to query window for this session ONLY

CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEMPDIR     --Sets the export directory
AS 'C:\TEMP\IMAGES\';


DECLARE                                 --Declare a series of variables
t_blob BLOB;
t_len NUMBER;
t_file_name VARCHAR2(1000);
t_output UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
t_TotalSize NUMBER;
t_position NUMBER := 1;
t_chucklen NUMBER := 4096;
t_chuck RAW(4096);
t_remain NUMBER;


BEGIN                                   --Begin the initial loop

  FOR var_a IN                          --Set the name of the cursor to be used
  (                                     --Define the cursor's properties
    SELECT id, imagedate, imageid
    FROM images
    WHERE imageid IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY imageid
  )
  LOOP                                  --export loop

  BEGIN                                 --Set the variables to be blank or 0
  --t_blob BLOB;
  t_len := 0;
  t_file_name := '';
  --t_output UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  t_TotalSize := 0;
  t_position  := 1;
  t_chucklen  := 4096;
  --t_chuck := (4096);
  t_remain := 0; 

      -- Get length of blob
      SELECT DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH (image), TO_CHAR (id)  || '-' || TO_CHAR (imagedate) || TO_CHAR (imageid) || '.jpg'
      INTO t_TotalSize, t_file_name
      FROM images
      WHERE imageid = var_a.imageid;

      t_remain := t_TotalSize;
      t_output := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('TEMPDIR', t_file_name, 'wb', 32760);

      -- Get BLOB
      SELECT image
      INTO t_blob 
      FROM images
      WHERE imageid= var_a.imageid;

      -- Retrieving BLOB
      WHILE t_position < t_TotalSize
        LOOP
        DBMS_LOB.READ (t_blob, t_chucklen, t_position, t_chuck);
        UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (t_output, t_chuck);
        UTL_FILE.FFLUSH (t_output);
        t_position := t_position + t_chucklen;
        t_remain := t_remain - t_chucklen;
          IF t_remain < 4096
            THEN
            t_chucklen := t_remain;
          END IF;

        END LOOP;
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (t_output);     --Close each file once it has been exported

      END;  

  END LOOP;

END;

/
```

Comment: since you're in the tool, we have tooling to do exactly what you want - no code required....let me know if you're interested

Comment: The code seems fine to me, only one things comes to mind and that is the size of t_chuck, why 4096? Try 32767 and also modify the t_chucklen to 32767, this may decrease the number of iterations of the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks J91321 I'll give that a go! t_chuck and t_chucklen values are just copies from the original scripts.